# Docker stuck in "rootless" mode on Rocky 9 (RHEL9)

Tags: docker, rocky-linux, rhel9

I tried setting up podman in rootless mode on Rocky Linux 9, but after running into a number of issues I uninstalled everything and just went back to Docker. I'm using a number of hosts all provisioned the same way, as Jenkins build nodes. When I run `docker run hello-world` as the `jenkins` user on and of these hosts, it works without issue. However, when I run from Jenkins, they immediately fail with a message that indidcates it's trying to use the "user" socket instead of `/var/run/docker.socket`:

```
+ whoami
jenkins
[Pipeline] sh
+ groups
users wheel mock docker
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/10002/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I made sure to revert any changes made during the rootless setup, including removing the entries for the Jenkins user in `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`. I also made sure to add `export DOCKER_HOST="unix:///var/run/docker.sock"` to `~/.bashrc` but I still encounter this error. I am sure this is something rather obvious I've overlooked, but I just can't see to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Podman. It took some time to figure out and I have detailed how to set up Podman as user (also on Rocky for me) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/734790/240147)